# iPad Split view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Is there any way when I rotate an iPad split view app that my view could take up the full screen instead of the menu or resize it? I like the portrait mode with the menu in the button.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can hide the master view when a `UIScrollView` is rotated to landscape orientation, you can't. That's not what `UIScrollView` is for. You'll have to write your own view controller class.