# UISplitViewController Full Screen For Detail View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a uisplitviewcontroller which loads a UIWebView as its detail view. I would like to allow the use to hide the RootViewController so that they can use the detail view controller in full screen.

The behavior is similar to that used by the Dropbox application. I'm not sure how to get this done. I've tried creating a new view controller and copy the webView, but there are issues whenever the user zooms the web view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the default split view only to a certain level..
Here are some related questions from SO:

[Hiding master view in split view app..???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020582/hiding-master-view-in-split-view-app)

[Ipad Split view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318572/ipad-split-view-controller)

but i think you've already read them.

I would suggest you to create your own custom controller as the default split view has very limited functionality.
You can look at [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController). It is a really good custom implementation similar to the UISplitViewController with much more flexibility.